# Grails won't run after clearing maven cache.

Tags: maven, grails

I had a projevt that was running fine until I cleared the Maven cache. Now I get:

```
org.apache.ant#ant;1.9.4: configuration not found in  org.apache.ant#ant;1.9.4: 'compile'. It was required from org.grails#grails-project-api;2.5.4 compile

cglib#cglib;2.2.2: configuration not found in cglib#cglib;2.2.2: 'compile'. It was required from org.grails#grails-plugin-testing;2.5.4     runtime

Resolve error obtaining dependencies:
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4
- cglib:cglib:2.2.2
```

And it happens no matter what I run: clean, clean-all, refresh-dependencies,.

The defacto repos are definedin the buildconfig:

mavenCentral(), grailsCentral(),grailsHome(), mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins", ect.

Comment: Do you have any proxy in the way, or any other network settings that would prevent communication with the standard repos?  Did you set your log level to 'warn' to get more info?

Comment: no proxies, log level is at warn already and doesn't give me much.

Comment: I don't suppose you could turn logging up to trace and get any more?  When this fails, does it fail immediately or take a while?